# Doesn't redirect to current page when logged in with google

Tags: flutter, firebase

```
  @override
  Future<UserModel> signInWithGoogle() async {
    GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    GoogleSignInAccount? _googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    if(_googleUser != null){
      GoogleSignInAuthentication _googleAuth = await _googleUser.authentication;
      if(_googleAuth.idToken != null && _googleAuth.accessToken != null){
        UserCredential result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
          GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken: _googleAuth.idToken,accessToken: _googleAuth.accessToken));
        return _userFromFirebase(result.user!);
      }else{
        return null!;
      }
    }else{
      return null!;
    }
```

**signInscreen**

```
void _signInGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    final _userViewModel = Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context,listen: false);
    UserModel _user = await _userViewModel.signInWithGoogle();
    if (_user != null) print("Oturum açan user id:" + _user.userId.toString());
  }

SocalIcon(iconSrc: "assets/icons/google-plus.svg",
press: () => _signInGoogle(context),),
```

When I login with google it is not redirected to current page without clicking back button in emulator. It saves the user to the database, but as I said, I cannot switch to the current page without clicking the back button. What is the reason?

Comment: Can you add a little more details? What issue are you facing when you try to sign in with google?

Comment: I do not encounter a problem, it just does not go to the page I want, but when I press the back button on the emulator, it goes to that page.
so it doesn't switch to the other page as soon as you log in